# How do I solve for the roots of $\sin(x) - x^2=0$?

Tags: equation-solving

I have defined `h[x] := Sin[x] - x^2`. When I submit `Solve[h[x] == 0, x]`, *Mathematica* tells me

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>

Answer (score 2):

```
h[x_] = Sin[x] - x^2;

Plot[h[x], {x, -.5, 1.25}]
```

[image]

Tell `Solve` or `NSolve` the domain to search

```
Solve[{h[x] == 0, -1/2 <= x <= 5/4}, x] // N
```

> {{x -> 0.}, {x -> 0.876726}}

```
NSolve[{h[x] == 0, -1/2 <= x <= 5/4}, x]
```

> {{x -> 0.}, {x -> 0.876726}}

The domain can just be Reals

```
Solve[h[x] == 0, x, Reals] // N
```

> {{x -> 0.}, {x -> 0.876726}}

Comment: +1, and `Reduce[h[x] == 0 && -1/2 < x < 5/4, {x}, Reals] // N` works also.

Comment: it would be might helpful if the `Solve/NSolve` warning msg suggested trying the domain Reals..

Comment: @george2079 - Mma always defaults to Complexes, if you want to restrict the variable to Reals you need to include Element[x, Reals] as a constraint or more restrictively specify the domain as Reals. It is consistent with this and expects you to specify your intent.

Comment: @BobHanlon - I do have to agree with george though. Its not entirely obvious to me, why Mma throws an error when you don't specify a domain, but works just fine when you do.

Answer (score 2):

I would direct you to the [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SolvingEquations.html), specifically Input No. 10.

To quote

> There is no explicit "closed form" solution for a transcendental equation like this. You can find an approximate numerical solution using FindRoot, and giving a starting value for x.

Like so:

```
FindRoot[Sin[x] - x^2, {x, 1}]
```

> ```
> {x -> 0.876726}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a rather simple function, you should approximately know about the distribution of its roots. One of them should be zero. If you don't you can use `Plot` to observe. For example,

```
Plot[-x^2 + Sin[x], {x, -0.5, 1}]
```

Then you can use

```
FindRoot[-x^2 + Sin[x] == 0, {x, 1}]
(*{x -> 0.876726}*)
```

to find out the other root.You can also obtain more digits by using `WorkingPrecision`

```
FindRoot[-x^2 + Sin[x] == 0, {x, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]
(*{x -> 0.8767262154}*)
```

When `Solve` does not work, you can try `NSolve` and `FindRoot`. You can read more about these two functions in the Documentations.